# Create Next and Previous Paging Using Sharepoint List and SpServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-object-model, spservices, csom

can anyone help me in Creating Next and Previous Paging for SharePoint List Using Sp-services With Client Side Template Binding .

Below is the Code Which I was Using.

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,
  listName: "EMail",
  CAMLQuery: queryText,
CAMLRowLimit: 15,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
     var pageindex=$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ListItemCollectionPositionNext");
var present_page_items=$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").size();
$('#endindex').empty().append(present_page_items);
var remaining_items=Total_listitems-present_page_items;
Total_listitems=0; $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function(i,k) { 
         var thisID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
         var FAd=$(this).attr("ows_From");
         var I_att=$(this).attr("ows_Attachments");
        var I_Sub="";
        if($(this).attr("ows_Title")){
        I_Sub=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
        }
         var I_Redt=$(this).attr("ows_ReceviedDateTime");var M_Ftr="<tr id='mailitem"+thisID+"'><td class='m-sm'><div class='ckbox ckbox-success'><input id='checkbox"+thisID+"' data-uniqueid="+thisID+" type='checkbox'><label for='checkbox"+thisID+"'></label></div></td><td class='xl-sm'><div class='media'><div class='media-body'><span class='media-meta pull-right'>"+I_Redt+"</span><h4 class='text-primary'>"+FAd+"</h4><p class='email-summary'>"+I_Sub+"</p></div></div></td</tr>";$(mailcontainer).append(M_Ftr);  });}});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to SPServices but does the job and it is very simple. 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92

I used knockout.js to bind the data to UI. it works pretty well.